# Django many-to-many override save method to increment a field instead of creating new objects

Tags: python, django

I have the following classes in my Models.py:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    prod_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        size_exists = Size.objects.filter(
             prod_size=self.prod_size, product_id=self.product_id
        ).exists()
        if size_exists:
           Size.objects.filter(
               prod_size=self.prod_size, product_id=self.product_id
           ).update(quantity=F('quantity')+1)
        else:
           super(Size, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Product(models.Model):
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size, related_name='products')
```

I want the save method to update the quantity field of Size if there already exists a prod_size with the same value and related to the same product_id. But I am having trouble with getting the product_id information from the intermediate table. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this is -

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.charfield(unique=True)

class Size(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    prod_size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ("product ", 'prod_size '),
        )
```

Now sizes are linked to each product, which means for a product you can have many sizes, and also in the size models you can not have duplicate product_size with respect to each product (meta property).

Now in your views check whether a product_size is available for the given product or not. If product_size is not there do a create or else update the quantity.

Comment: But I dont want to "not have duplicate product_size with respect to each product". I want to be able to have multiple same sizes for a product. For example if I have 3 pairs of a shoe with size 6.

Comment: the code is exactly the same as what you are asking for. try to understand. size will be 6 and quantity will be 3, in first case. now you can not again have size 6 and quantity 4 for the same product. two same sizes are not allowed, quantities can be as many as you want.

Comment: Ah makes sense now thank you so much! One more question, do I need the check in views to update my quantity now? since I cant add a same size with same product anyways because of unique_together wouldn't that be redundant ? thanks again

Comment: Now in your views check whether a product_size is available for the given product or not. If product_size is not there do a create or else update the quantity.

Comment: I am really sorry I dont understand why I need that check? I cannot create a product with the same prod_size anyways because of unique_together.  So there will never be "else update quantity" since it cant exist in the first place.  Basically if I have a product with same prod_sizes, I only have to put in the quantity once when I create the product And in the future when customers purchase a quantity, I will just decrement it from the maximum initial quantity for that size value? Is there any flaw in this logic? I am so sorry if I Am not understanding something simple thank you very much

Comment: In views, I mean post method, when you try to add a new size and quantity of a product. if it isn't clear do write. I will explain in detail

Comment: When I add a new size to the same product, it works as expected (new size 5.5, prodid 1 qty1). When I add a same size to the same product, it works as expected (Error: Size with this Product and Prod size already exists. expected because unique_together only allows me to initialize prod and prod size uniquely and thus prevents having size 5.5 prodid 1 quantity 1 from appearing in db again). Why Do I have to change or add a post method to the views if I'm not even able to update quantity because of unique together. Please let me know if I am missing something thank you very much for your time

Comment: suppose at first purchase of shoes size 6 quantity 3, system will allow you to create this and then on 2nd time with same shoe, same size 6 and quantity 4, this time system will throw error can not create. but I think you will want your shoe quantity of size 6 to be updated to 7 (3+4). so elling to check if same size already existes update the quantity. If this is not your requirement ignore this.